# How do I redirect from an old domain to a new domain in MediaWiki and nginx?

Tags: domains, dns, 301-redirect, mediawiki, nginx

I'm going to move from old domain to new domain.
I fixed all the settings, but none worked.
While entering the old domain name in the url, I will encounter the message of not redirecting to the new domain.

Comment: You seem to have a redirection loop. `https://motocode.ir/` is redirecting to itself.

Comment: Can you please provide some more specific information?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this in your `server` block should work:

```
...
server_name old.example;
return 301 $scheme://new.example$request_uri;
...
```

Comment: Thanks dear Friends. The problem has been resolved. Thank you